# How to exchange rows for columns in R

Tags: r, search

I have a dataframe that consists of 47 columns and 592 rows. I plan to analyze it using propensity scoring and believe that predict() will give me what I want: a propensity score is the conditional probability of assignment to a particular treatment given a vector of observed covariates. Predict() delivers probabilities. So the first question is: is predict() the way to go?
Assuming for now that predict() is the way to go, I believe that I need the data that it is to analyze to be my existing dataframe with the rows and columns exchanged. I do not know how to do this in R and would very much appreciate guidance as to how to do this.

Answer (score 8):

It is called *transposing* your data and the function for that is `t`.

Beware that it will turn your data.frame (with possibly different classes for different columns) into a matrix (only one class of data throughout) so your data may be coerced.

Comment: Many Thanks. I could do with some hand-holding here. One column is age as a continuous variable. Does this mean that I cannot use t ? What package does t come from ? Please would you give me an example of the syntax for how to use t (arguments, etc)

Comment: It is part of the base package (i.e. comes with R by default) and you can access the documentation by running `help(t)` or `?t`.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, floden. I've looked at the documentation for t(data) and as.matrix but still cannot see whether I can proceed if  one column (age) is a continuous variable with all other columns binary (0 or 1). If I have to I can retrace my steps and categorize age so that all columns are of the same class to start with, but do I have to do this? Please bear with me on this. Best Regards, Martin

Comment: With values in `{0, 1}`, these columns are probably of class `integer`, while your `age` column is `numeric`. When transposing, everything will become `numeric`. I don't know what you plan to do with your transposed data but it is unlikely it will be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use function

```
t(data)
```

on your data.